# Black Imageview while resuming activity or soft keyboard changes

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I want to add a background image,

Here is the XML code

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/chatroompage"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I use glide for loading image.

```
   Glide.with(this).load(imageuri).into(background);
```

works fine on the first load. But when I use a keyboard or resume the activity the image becomes black.

Thanx for the help.

Comment: Remove the background from `RelativeLayout` Also use a placeholder image while the image is being loaded.

Comment: I need the RelativeLayout background, use of image background is optional. If in the setting there is image background then i add code for image background

Comment: But I'll try doing that

Comment: And same problem.. @RachitMishra

Comment: add `android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation"` in menifest inside your activity.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure there is no other background? background color on or around the ImageView?

Comment: No there is no other background colors @RachitMishra

Answer (score 0):

Put this code:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

entry inside `<Activity >` tag in `manifest` file.

put your glide set image code within this method:

```
      @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Glide.with(this).load(imageuri).into(background)
       .load(getItem(position))
       .asBitmap()
       .imageDecoder(new StreamBitmapDecoder(imageView.getContext(), 
        DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888))
       .override(400, 300)
       .fitCenter()
       .skipMemoryCache( true );
    }
```

You noticed that we called .skipMemoryCache( true ) to specifically tell Glide to skip the memory cache.

References:

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/738

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/527

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/673

Comment: It somehow fixes the keyboard problem, But when i tap on home button and go back to activity, same black screen

Comment: are you using glide in Activity or fragment ? @NoobCoder

Comment: In the activity.

Comment: Tried it, Still getting same problem.

Comment: What why skip memory cache. You are saying glide to fetch image every time?